# MongoDB - $setIsSubset operator not working with $match stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I constructed a query like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$match: {$setIsSubset: [['hello', 'you'], '$words']}}])
```

I want to return all documents where the array of the field 'words' contains the  strings ['hello', 'you'].

Executing this query i get this error:

> "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $setIsSubset"

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) if you want to use `$setIsSubset` (which is an expresion) inside `$match`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $setIsSubset: [["hello", "you"], "$words"]}
            }
        }
])
```

For MongoDB versions lower than **3.6** you can use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ { $setIsSubset: [["hello", "you"], "$words"]}, true ] },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I get the same error but with $expr: `"errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr"`

Comment: @BetterSaveThanSorry you must be using MongoDB lower than 3.6. You can try with `$redact` in that case as in my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
 db.test.aggregate([{$match: {'words': {'$all': ["hello", "you"] }}}])
```