# How do I filter recipes from the database?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have a collection with recipes, that looks like this:

```
{
  "Name": "Omelet",
  "Ingredients": ["Eggs", "Milk", "Butter"]
},
{
  "Name": "Pancakes",
  "Ingredients": ["Eggs", "Milk", "Butter", "Flour", "Sugar", "Salt"]
},
{
  "Name": "Random recipe",
  "Ingredients": ["Eggs", "Milk"]
}
```

I'm trying to get recipes with ingredients that are fully contained in the query. For example, if I have in query eggs, milk and butter, then I have to get omelet and "random recipe" from collection above, but not pancakes, because I don't have another 3 necessary ingredients for it. If I have only eggs and milk, then it must return only "random recipe". In other words, I only want recipes that can be made with the available ingredients. I searched the documentation, but I could not find exactly how this should be implemented. Any ideas? I'm using Golang for my back-end, so it will be better if you write an example on it. I would be grateful for any help.

For now I wrote this function, which returns all recipes with certain ingredients, but this does not take into account missing ingredients and recipes that do not need all of the transferred ingredients:

```
func GetTestRecipesFromDB(ingredients []string) *[]Recipe {
    collection := client.Database("food_db").Collection("recipes")

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10 * time.Second)

    var recipes []Recipe
    var cursor *mongo.Cursor

    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.D{
        {"Ingredients", bson.D{{"$all", ingredients}}},
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &recipes); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    return &recipes
}
```

**EDIT:** according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915963/mongodb-setissubset-operator-not-working-with-match-stage) (thx @MontgomeryWatts for suggestion) I wrote this in Go and it works:

```
    query := bson.M{
        "$match" : bson.M{
            "$expr" : bson.M{
                "$setIsSubset": []interface{}{
                    "$Ingredients",
                    ingredients,
                },
            },
        },
    }

    cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, []bson.M{query})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with an aggregation pipeline using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html#filter-aggregation)

- $match so that you only consider recipes with at least one matching ingredient
- $addFields to create `OtherIngredient` field using $filter to eliminate the queried array of ingredients from `Ingredients`
- $match to pick only recipes with no other indredients
- $project to remove the temporary field

```
[
  {$match: {Ingredients: {
        $in: ["Eggs","Milk","Butter"]
  }}},
  { $addFields: {
      OtherIngredient: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Ingredients",
          cond: {$not: {$in: [
                "$$this",
                ["Eggs","Milk","Butter"]
          ]}}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$match: {"OtherIngredient": []}},
  {$project: {OtherIngredient: 0}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gxakRZjw54j)

Comment: Will this solution be better than using $setIsSubset?

Comment: Probably not, I always forget that operator exitsts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know Golang but this is what you need (`$function` is new MongoDB 4.4):

```js
let filter = ["Eggs", "Milk", "Butter"];

db.recipes.find({
    $expr: {
        $function: {
            body: function(ingredients, filter) {

                for (let i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
                    if (filter.indexOf(ingredients[i]) < 0) return false;
                }

                return true
            },
            args: ["$Ingredients", filter],
            lang: "js"
        }
    }
});
```